# fullCalendar eventClick on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

when I try to use the eventclick on a mobile device it always fires the dayClick event in stead of the eventclick. I tried:

```
$('.fc-event').live("click", function () {
    alert("you just clicked");
});
```

and

```
eventClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            alert('you just clicked');
 }
```

it works fine on my pc but mobile seems to always fire the dayClick and never the EventClick.. Even when I put  selectable: false it still fires the dayClick event. What lines should I remove from the fullcalendar.min.js to remove all dayClick events.. at least I think this is the most optimal (and maybe the only) solution in my case because I don't need the dayClick at all

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.fc-event').live("click", function () {
    alert("you just clicked");
});
```

above code is not supported as per the documentation. Make sure to remove it from the code base.

For day click and event click you must use as specified in the documentation

```
eventClick:function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  alert("clicked on event");
},
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  alert("clicked on day");
}
```

Also make sure to wrap inside the fullcalendar function as below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        alert('View: ' + view.name);

        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

    },
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        alert("clicked on day");
    }
});
```

Read the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/). I also using it for my jQuery Mobile project and it works fine.

Comment: this works perfect on my pc but only fires dayclick on my phone. it might be because I'm testing on a Windows Phone. I will test this later today on an Android device and keep you posted. Thank you for the fast response

Comment: Yeah might be the issue with Win Phone. I have tested it on iOS and Android (iPad, iPhone, Android Tablet, Nexus S) all works fine.

Comment: btw I hope you didn't use `(document).ready(function() {});` instead you used `pageshow` or `pagecreate` events as suggested here http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/.

Comment: This does indeed work on Android so it seems to be (another) Windows Phone "feature". So if I could somehow disable the dayClick then I guess it should fire the eventClick because my project will have to be Windows Phone compatible.. any idea?

Comment: no disabling dayclick is not the solution. dayClick is fired when u click on the empty space of the dayview. eventClick is fired when you click on an event itself. You might have to look for a hack. Check whether your mobile browser is html5 compatible. Is it windows 8 phone?

Comment: I found a little workaround that solves my problem on windows phone. use the dayClick to get all the events on that day, show the first one and provide some sort of navigation to go to the next/prev event on that day! That solves my problem and gives android/iOS users an "extra feature" that gives them the first event when selecting a day!

Comment: @Utarehpson way to go. If I come across same issue in future, that'd be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use eventAfterRender to attach a click event.  It worked for us on iOS

```js
 eventAfterRender: function(calEvent, element, view)
            {
                $(element).click(function(){
                  alert('clicked!!');
            });
```